# A survey on the economics of loyalty programs

Tags: reference-request

Is there a good survey that covers the theory and empirics of loyalty programs? I am thinking of programs like Amazon Prime, Starbucks, and airlines miles/points. What are the mechanisms? Are they effective in a causal sense?

Answer (score 1):

A relevant literature is that on **the economics of switching costs**. There are many papers in this literature and a number of surveys, but I would recommend [this paper](http://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/users/klemperer/competition.pdf) by Klemperer for a concise combination of survey and theory. A more comprehensive survey can be found in [this handbook chapter](http://www.nuff.ox.ac.uk/users/klemperer/Farrell_klempererWP.pdf) by Farrell and Klemperer.

The basic idea is that loyalty programmes (among other things) create a cost for consumers who contemplate switching to another supplier. This literature studies how such costs influence strategic behaviour and competition between firms.